# Change Tracking on multi tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables as below.

**Blog**:

```
BlogId, CateId, BlogName
------------------------------
1        1      'Blog name 1'
2        1      'Blog name 2'
3        2      'Blog name 3'
4        2      'Blog name 3'
```

**Category**:

```
CateId, CateName
-----------------
1       'Cate 1'
2       'Cate 2'
```

I execute these queries:

```
update Categogy 
set CateName = 'Sport' 
where CateId = 1

update Blog 
set BlogName = 'today news' 
where BlogId = 4
```

I want to perform change tracking on both the tables, and return the result as below:

```
BlogId, CateId, BlogName
1        1      'Blog name 1'
2        1      'Blog name 2'
4        2      'today news'
```

Does anybody have any solution please help!

Thanks!

Comment: you should use a ON UPDATE  **TRIGGER**. And the way to declare it depends on your RDBMS which you have not specified

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Hi, I added tag 'sql-server-2012'. Thanks!